# Sign in with Apple ID in react + django rest framework project

Tags: reactjs, django, django-allauth

I'm working on the project setup with react + Django rest framework.
The error I'm getting now is invalid client.

In react, I used 2 packages react-social-login-buttons and react-apple-login button.
I used 2 packages to succeed to get code and id_token.
Then I sent code and id_token like this: {"code": code_value, "id_token": id_token_value}.

But when I call this API, I'm getting the following error.

It would be great if anyone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry for short description. I can provide more details when reaching out to me.
Thanks.

Comment: did you manage to figure it out? 

I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: @KaranV Not yet. how about you?

Answer (score -1):

django-allauth is good library for apple login

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I used django-allauth. And I got id_token and code and sent to the Django Rest Framework. But it's not working.